# Hot Deployment with Jetty Plugin for Gradle

Tags: gradle, jetty

I am currently using the Jetty plugin for gradle for development:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

...

jettyRunWar {
  httpPort = 8080
 reload = 'automatic'
  scanIntervalSeconds = 2
  daemon = false 
}

jettyRun {
  httpPort = 8080
  reload = 'automatic'
  scanIntervalSeconds = 2
  daemon = false 
}
```

However, the hot deployment is not working as expected. When using `gradle jettyRunWar`, the plugin seems to reload the context when using `gradle war`, but nothing changes really. When using `gradle jettyRun`, the reloading works, but JSF is no longer working:

```
Could not instantiate listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
AnnotationConfigurator does not found classes for annotations in /WEB-INF/classes/ . This could happen because maven jetty plugin is used (goal jetty:run). Try configure org.apache
.myfaces.annotation.SCAN_PACKAGES init parameter or use jetty:run-exploded instead.
```

Any ideas how to get one of these options to work? Setting the mentioned parameter leads just to more exceptions.